# Trying to find the second largest value after grouping by even number python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, data-analysis

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

values = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4])
example_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': values,
    'even': values % 2 == 0,
    'above_three': values > 3 
}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

# Find second largest value in each group
if True:
    def second_largest(xs):
        sorted_xs = xs.sort(inplace=False, ascending=False)
        return sorted_xs.iloc[1]

grouped_data = example_df.groupby('even')
print grouped_data['value'].apply(second_largest)
```

The traceback says the following

```
AttributeError                      
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-94-251c7e3ea488> in
```

()
        14 
        15     grouped_data = example_df.groupby('even')
   ---> 16     print grouped_data['value'].apply(second_largest)

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in
```

apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
       714         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
       715         with option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):
   --> 716             return self._python_apply_general(f)
       717 
       718     def _python_apply_general(self, f):

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in
```

_python_apply_general(self, f)
       718     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
       719         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj,
   --> 720                                                    self.axis)
       721 
       722         return self._wrap_applied_output(

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in
```

apply(self, f, data, axis)    1800             # group might be
   modified    1801             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
   -> 1802             res = f(group)    1803             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):    1804                 mutated = True

in second_largest(xs)
         9 if True:
        10     def second_largest(xs):
   ---> 11         sorted_xs = xs.sort(inplace=False, ascending=False)
        12         print sorted_xs
        13         return sorted_xs.iloc[1]

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in
```

**getattr**(self, name)    3079             if name in self._info_axis:    3080                 return self[name]
   -> 3081             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    3082     3083     def **setattr**(self, name, value):

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Are you assuming a Series object is a Python list with a sort function?

Comment: No, I am assuming I am using the sort function on a numpy array and i use the apply function to apply to one column in a series object (a pandas series).

Comment: Did you mean `sort_values`? There is no sort function for a numpy series, as the error says. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html